# How to parse JSON data from url response

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have a problem while parsing json data from url response, I get

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

here is my jquery code:

```
$("#row1, #row2, #row3, #row4, #row5").on("click", "td", function() {
    kursi = $( this ).attr("id");
    var lru = "myURL";
    //$("#link").attr('href', lru); 
    alert(lru);

    $.ajax({
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data) {
                var jos = data;     
                var myvar = $.parseJSON(jos);
                alert(myvar);
                $('span').html(jos);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the response supposed to be like this:

```
{
"err_code": 0,
"book_code": "UBGF53",
"wagon_code": "EKSI",
"wagon_no": 1,
"seat": [
    "3A",
    "3C"
]
}
```

I've done this before on php using "file_get_contents" and "json_decode" and it works just fine,but I'm really new to jquery. I really appreciate any response;

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to see if your json is valid

Comment: The response you're getting is not valid JSON. You have a line break in the first property name, and you have mismatching quotes.

Comment: First validate the json whether is valid json or not... USe http://jsonlint.com/ to validate... Then use JSON.parse(jos);

Comment: oww sorry man,I mistyped the response.
Let's say that the response is right,would my code catch the data??